# How to disable emojis button in react native keyboard?

Tags: react-native

I need to disable emojis for my react native keyboard app. When my keyboard appear, the emoji icon is visible and i need to make it unavailable to prevent user to insert emojis in texts.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I've been searching information but I found nothing. Anyway, what's the problem if the user insert a emoji? It is just like a "char", so, each emoji have it own "char". The way I think it could work is to filter the user text and check if the text contains an emoji char code. And if it contains it, reject it! Here you have the emoji code table! https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Answer (score 12):

The exact way to disable emoji is to set '**ascii-capable**' for **iOS** and '**visible-password**' for **Android** to TextInput Props **keyboardType**.

```
<TextInput
    keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ascii-capable' : 'visible-password'}
/>
```

Comment: WARNING! 'visible-password' for Android will break Swift/Swipe functionality in keyboard. I do not recommend this solution.

Comment: So what solution do you recommend?

Answer (score 10):

This is what I got when attempting this problem:

- the **keyboardType**="ascii-capable" does not work on Android because it is specific to iOS only accordding to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#keyboardtype
- using **keyboardType**="email-address" does not hide the emoji button in every keyboard on Android

My solution to the above limitations was to remove any emoji character that the might be entered. To do that, I did the following:

- Search for a regex that covers most of the emoji unicodes. After trying a number of regex, I ended up using the one this https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex. It's not perfect but it covers most emojis.
- Create a function that runs every time a new value is entered
- Use the function in the Text Input value prop

**Function:**

```
 const removeEmojis = (string) => {
  // emoji regex from the emoji-regex library
  const regex = /\uD83C\uDFF4(?:\uDB40\uDC67\uDB40\uDC62(?:\uDB40\uDC65\uDB40\uDC6E\uDB40\uDC67|\uDB40\uDC77\uDB40\uDC6C\uDB40\uDC73|\uDB40\uDC73\uDB40\uDC63\uDB40\uDC74)\uDB40\uDC7F|\u200D\u2620\uFE0F)|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC69\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67]))|\uD83D\uDC68(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83D\uDC68|(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67]))|\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDB0-\uDDB3])|(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D(?:\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDB0-\uDDB3]))|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])|\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDB0-\uDDB3])|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|(?:\uD83D\uDC41\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8|\uD83D\uDC69(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83D\uDC68(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])|(?:(?:\u26F9|\uD83C[\uDFCB\uDFCC]|\uD83D\uDD75)\uFE0F|\uD83D\uDC6F|\uD83E[\uDD3C\uDDDE\uDDDF])\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|(?:\u26F9|\uD83C[\uDFCB\uDFCC]|\uD83D\uDD75)(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|(?:\uD83C[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA]|\uD83D[\uDC6E\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6]|\uD83E[\uDD26\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDD6-\uDDDD])(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|\u200D[\u2640\u2642])|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])\uFE0F|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC69\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|\uD83D\uDC68(?:\u200D(?:(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C\uDFF3\uFE0F\u200D\uD83C\uDF08|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC67|\uD83D\uDC69(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D(?:\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDB0-\uDDB3])|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83C\uDDF6\uD83C\uDDE6|\uD83C\uDDFD\uD83C\uDDF0|\uD83C\uDDF4\uD83C\uDDF2|\uD83D\uDC69(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C\uDDED(?:\uD83C[\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFA])|\uD83C\uDDEC(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEE\uDDF1-\uDDF3\uDDF5-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFE])|\uD83C\uDDEA(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDED\uDDF7-\uDDFA])|\uD83C\uDDE8(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDEE\uDDF0-\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA-\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF2(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF3(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF4\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDFC(?:\uD83C[\uDDEB\uDDF8])|\uD83C\uDDFA(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEC\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF8\uDDFE\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF0(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDEE\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDEF(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF5])|\uD83C\uDDF8(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDF4\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFD-\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDEE(?:\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEA\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9])|\uD83C\uDDFF(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDF2\uDDFC])|\uD83C\uDDEB(?:\uD83C[\uDDEE-\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF7])|\uD83C\uDDF5(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEA-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDF3\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFC\uDDFE])|\uD83C\uDDE9(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF9(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDED\uDDEF-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDE7(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEF\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF])|[#\*0-9]\uFE0F\u20E3|\uD83C\uDDF1(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDE8\uDDEE\uDDF0\uDDF7-\uDDFB\uDDFE])|\uD83C\uDDE6(?:\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF7(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF4\uDDF8\uDDFA\uDDFC])|\uD83C\uDDFB(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF3\uDDFA])|\uD83C\uDDFE(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF9])|(?:\uD83C[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA]|\uD83D[\uDC6E\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6]|\uD83E[\uDD26\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDD6-\uDDDD])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|(?:\u26F9|\uD83C[\uDFCB\uDFCC]|\uD83D\uDD75)(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|(?:[\u261D\u270A-\u270D]|\uD83C[\uDF85\uDFC2\uDFC7]|\uD83D[\uDC42\uDC43\uDC46-\uDC50\uDC66\uDC67\uDC70\uDC72\uDC74-\uDC76\uDC78\uDC7C\uDC83\uDC85\uDCAA\uDD74\uDD7A\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDE4C\uDE4F\uDEC0\uDECC]|\uD83E[\uDD18-\uDD1C\uDD1E\uDD1F\uDD30-\uDD36\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDD1-\uDDD5])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|(?:[\u231A\u231B\u23E9-\u23EC\u23F0\u23F3\u25FD\u25FE\u2614\u2615\u2648-\u2653\u267F\u2693\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26CE\u26D4\u26EA\u26F2\u26F3\u26F5\u26FA\u26FD\u2705\u270A\u270B\u2728\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2795-\u2797\u27B0\u27BF\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]|\uD83C[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDDE6-\uDDFF\uDE01\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE36\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF20\uDF2D-\uDF35\uDF37-\uDF7C\uDF7E-\uDF93\uDFA0-\uDFCA\uDFCF-\uDFD3\uDFE0-\uDFF0\uDFF4\uDFF8-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDC3E\uDC40\uDC42-\uDCFC\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD4B-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDD7A\uDD95\uDD96\uDDA4\uDDFB-\uDE4F\uDE80-\uDEC5\uDECC\uDED0-\uDED2\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF4-\uDEF9]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDD3A\uDD3C-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD70\uDD73-\uDD76\uDD7A\uDD7C-\uDDA2\uDDB0-\uDDB9\uDDC0-\uDDC2\uDDD0-\uDDFF])|(?:[#*0-9\xA9\xAE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614\u2615\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u2648-\u2653\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u267F\u2692-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26B0\u26B1\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26D4\u26E9\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7-\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708-\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]|\uD83C[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDDE6-\uDDFF\uDE01\uDE02\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF93\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E-\uDFF0\uDFF3-\uDFF5\uDFF7-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDCFD\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD49-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73-\uDD7A\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDDA4\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE8\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA-\uDE4F\uDE80-\uDEC5\uDECB-\uDED2\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF0\uDEF3-\uDEF9]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDD3A\uDD3C-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD70\uDD73-\uDD76\uDD7A\uDD7C-\uDDA2\uDDB0-\uDDB9\uDDC0-\uDDC2\uDDD0-\uDDFF])\uFE0F|(?:[\u261D\u26F9\u270A-\u270D]|\uD83C[\uDF85\uDFC2-\uDFC4\uDFC7\uDFCA-\uDFCC]|\uD83D[\uDC42\uDC43\uDC46-\uDC50\uDC66-\uDC69\uDC6E\uDC70-\uDC78\uDC7C\uDC81-\uDC83\uDC85-\uDC87\uDCAA\uDD74\uDD75\uDD7A\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B-\uDE4F\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6\uDEC0\uDECC]|\uD83E[\uDD18-\uDD1C\uDD1E\uDD1F\uDD26\uDD30-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDD1-\uDDDD])/g

  return string.replace(regex, '')
}
```

**Text Input**

```
render() {
    return(
        <TextInput
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
            value={removeEmojis(this.state.text)}
         />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TextInput has a keyboardType property that will let you fix this issue. But android and ios handle it differently. This is what worked for me with both platforms.

```
<TextInput keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'email-address' : 'ascii-capable'} ... />
```

Comment: it shows emoji in android

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the `keyboardType="ascii-capable"` in the `TextIput`, in order to hide the emojis option on the keyboard, like:

```html
<TextInput keyboardType="ascii-capable" ... />
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: As @Marcelo Dauane said above...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52224180/659272

"the keyboardType="ascii-capable" does not work on Android because it is specific to iOS only accordding to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#keyboardtype"